# Cast from 'URL' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: swift

I am having an issue right now dealing with deep linking in iOS. I am new to Swift so I am a little lost here. I get that I am converting `URL` to `String` already, but for some reason I am getting the error:

> Cast from 'URL' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

when I am trying to reference `webpageUrl`.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

```
if let webpageUrl = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/this/that") {
    //application.open(webpageUrl)
    // alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: webpageUrl as? String, preferredStyle: .alert)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    // alert
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just cast a URL to string, but there are properties on the URL object you can use. This is a fairly straight forward issue, you should always check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) if your unsure on something

Change this:

```
message: webpageUrl as? String
```

to

```
message: webpageUrl.absoluteString
```

Comment: Thanks that worked and yes your right checking docs first. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: absoluteString often gives the wrong result. you probably want `theURL.path`

Comment: @DuncanC No, this is not a file path, it's a proper URL given the example in the code.